# How to Install AMX TIBCO BPM

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-business-works, tibco-rv

First I have installed the Red HAT Enterprise Linux 7.4 and then Installed the JDK 8 on it.

I have 5 folders in my downloads :

1. assembly_tibco_com_tibco
2. EMS 8.3.0
3. TIB_amx_3.3.0_HF-017
4. TIB_amx-bpm_4.2.0_linux24gl23_x86_64
5. TIB_business-studio-bpm-edition_4.2.0_win_x86_64

Now I want to installed AMX TIBCO BPM.

NOTE : Oracle 12c is also installed on another machine.

How should I take a start ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A. Run TIBCOUniversalInstaller  ==> for GUI mode

B. Run TIBCOUniversalInstaller -console ==> for console mode

C. Run TIBCOUniversalInstaller -silent ==> for silent mode

1. Open the TIBCOUniversalInstaller-amx-bpm_n.n.n.silent file
2. Specify the required entry keys.
3. Make sure that all drive letters are specified in upper case, otherwise the silent installation may fail.

Comment: Many Thanks for the reply @B2B
Any URL for complete installation ?

Comment: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/amx-bpm/4.2.0/doc/html/bpmhelp/GUID-F14F1C80-CE2F-427E-9029-C9D83D710488.html